# Class variables messing up

Tags: php, class, variables

consider this code :

```
Class Controller_xyz extends Controller
{
    protected $res=' ';
    public function action_reg()
    {
         $this->res="blah";
         $x="blah"
         echo $this->res;
         echo $x;
    }
}
```

output :

```
b
blah
```

why am I not able to change class variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a typo @

`$x="blah"` (missing `;`)

Working code: http://ideone.com/jmICU

<sup>(Controller stripped out)</sup>

Please let me know if my answer has worked.

Comment: Oops.. that was a typo while filling in this forum.. thanks for pointing it out..

Comment: I edited in http://ideone.com/brbGZ   Check now.. It behaves as described in question

Comment: Your example provided in your question is not the same as you wrote @ Ideone. The problem is you define `$res` as string then later you assign a variable to it as an array. Please take a look @ http://ideone.com/0ayLi now it works again.

Comment: works :)  as you said, I shouldn't have initialized it to string.. or atleast, not to character '' (it worked when I tried $res="").  Cool man, if I had enough rep to give you a vote, i'd have :) thanks..

Answer (score -2):

It is NOT class variable but instance variable if you define/access it this way.

Most of the time in PHP, i forget including $ in variable name. 
Try as

$this->$res = "blah";

Comment: Are you sure about this?